# Geometry Nodes instantiate mesh primitives at points

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to instantiate line meshes with a random number of segments at the vertices of a mesh.

Blender *2.93* has shiny new *mesh primitive* nodes to instantiate meshes in your geometry nodes network. However the `Point Instance` only accepts the type `Object` or `string` and since all the *mesh* nodes have the output type of `Geometry` it seems to me that it's impossible to create a number of meshes at certain point locations.

[image]

Comment: Planned for 3.0.0. See https://developer.blender.org/T89657

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a workaround:

1. Create an *Empty* object that stays at the world origin.
2. Create a collection named 'lines'.
3. Create a *Mesh* object in the collection, and add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier.
4. Create a network that outputs the position of the mesh object.
   [image: Get position of current object]
5. Create a network that creates the geometry based on the location. I've used the 'x' offset here to create a line segment with 'x' offset count. The *DeltaX* input is the ratio for each increment.
   [image]
6. Now duplicate the mesh object until you have enough variations. (You can do this quickly by doing duplicating once, offsetting by *DeltaX* and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
7. Reference the 'lines' collection with the 'Point Instance' node to access the geometry points.

Answer (score 2):

It's now natively supported in Version 3.0+ :

[image]

Simply plug the mesh data output into the instance input to instance the geometry.